# How to autofill column based on total in another column

Tags: google-sheets

As you can see in the screenshot below, I have one column that is recording a daily count, while the second column is a sum of this count over an entire campaign.

How can I get the second column to auto-fill so that it sums from cell O3 down to the correct point - for instance cell P5 should be `=sum(O3:O5)`, cell P6 should be `=sum(O3:O6)`, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following formula in P3:

```
=SUM(O$3:O3)
```

By locking the  starting row of the range with `$`, We achieve the intended result.

Comment: There's a reason for the minimum character limit.  Please add some additional explanation.

Answer (score 0):

- cell **P3**: **`=O3`**
- cell **P4**: **`=IF(O4<>"";SUM(O4+P3);)`**
- select cell **P4** and drag the blue square down to the end